# How do you create different CSS for dynamically generated elements?

Tags: html, css

How do you generate different CSS for dynamically generated elements?

My issue is here: we have a date picker widget which has table `th` elements generated, with text-align: left. When it's left, the `th`'s align left, but the right side `>>` squishes together. The opposite problem occurs when I align them right. What I need to do is apply `align left` to the first `<<` and `align right` to the last `>>`. But these items are being generated dynamically. SCSS rules are being used.

`th { text-align: left }`

[image]

`th {text-align: right }`

[image]

---

Each piece of the date picker, the <<, June 2007, and >> are in different `th` within `tr`:

[image]

[image]

Comment: css sudo classes. th:last-child, th:first-child. you can use these to target the first and last element.

Comment: Why do you keep dragging Sass into questions that can't possibly be solved by Sass?  This is the 3rd time now I've had to fix tags on your questions.

Comment: It would also seem that you have problems with margins and/or padding here.  If the `<th>` elements were all the right size with the proper spacing, it shouldn't matter how you align your text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) and [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) pseudo-classes:

```
th:first-child { text-align: left; }
th:last-child { text-align: right; }
```

Comment: One additional comment: If you have to support lower than IE9 - which, unfortunately does happen in the real non-ideal world - then :last-child will not work. However, you could set th { text-align: right; } th:first-child { text-align: left; } and for the middle: th[colspan="5"] { text-align: center; }

Answer (score 0):

Another solution can be set **text-align:center** to all th elements. But its'n what you exactly want, maybe.